# .NET 2.0 vs .NET 4.0 runtime allocation performance

Tags: .net, runtime

after migrating from .NET 3.5 (.NET 2.0 runtime) to NET 4.0 we can see a decreased performance when allocating larger chunks of memory. Please review the following test code. It is a minimalistic testing program representing a real world scenario we are using. Can anybody explain the dramatic difference between .NET 2.0 and 4.0 runtime, which is *much* slower? Steps to reproduce:

1. Import the code into a C# console application.
2. Set platform target to x64.
3. Target .NET 3.5 and make a Release build.
4. Run the EXE (do NOT run from IDE!) and type "test" into the console.
5. Wait for the results.
6. Repeat for .NET 4.0.

Thanks.

Alex

```
    class Program {

    static DateTime firstdate, lastdate;

    const int CHUNKSIZE =  10 * 1024 * 1024; //  10 MB.
    const int TRIALS = 10000;

    static void startmeasure() {

        firstdate = DateTime.Now;

    }

    static void stopmeasure() {

        lastdate = DateTime.Now;

        var duration = lastdate.Subtract(firstdate);

        Console.WriteLine("Test duration:" + duration.TotalSeconds.ToString());

    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string input;

        do {

            input = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (input) {

                case "test":

                    handletest();

                    break;

            }

        } while (input != "exit");

    }

    static void handletest() {

        startmeasure();

        byte[] data;

        for (int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {

            data = getdata(CHUNKSIZE);

        }

        stopmeasure();

    }

    static byte[] getdata(int size) {

        return new byte[size];

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code would be significantly easier to read if you didn't have quite so many blank lines. Whitespace is useful, but not after *every* line... (I'd also advise you to follow appropriate naming conventions even for throwaway code - it makes it easier for everyone to read.)

Comment: This is a side-effect of RyuJIT, the rewrite of the x64 jitter that first shipped in .NET 4.6.  The old jitter had a much more aggressive optimizer, a feature that had a knack for turning into a bug.  The old optimizer completely removes the getdata() call since its return value is never used.  Big difference of course.  That you actually found the perf problem is not so likely, nobody really writes code like this.   Do consider using a profiler on the real code so you can narrow down the expensive part of it.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans pointed out, the answer lies in the different ways .NET 2 and 4 optimize fast memory allocations and early object reclaiming. Seeing .NET 4 performing slower in this kind of test code does not mean that its performance is lower for real applications, so this is just a special situation.

A.